# How to read attribute value having special character in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a requirement where I am getting id from a json response.
 **id="TICKET NUMBER (TK)"**

The html component contains an attribute CI which has same value as ID.

When I am trying to access any attribute using ID, I am getting error as "unrecognized expression"

This is because of the special character present in Id.

Below is my sample html

```
<div class="col-sm-4" id="TICKET NUMBER (TK)" CI="TICKET NUMBER (TK)">
  <label>Ticket</label>
  <div>
    <span></span>
    <input  id="ticket"  ng-model="Ticket" >
  </div>
</div>
```

Please help me on resolving the issue.

Comment: Can you please provide some more code or plnkr?

Comment: Id define without space.

Comment: The id attribute is not allowed to include spaces.  Using parens is also asking for trouble.

Comment: @ shraddha: I will be getting values of id  from json response

Comment: @ katmanco : what part of code you need.

Comment: I haven't tested yet. Will mark it as soon as I test it. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**@Jefrey** is correct, `id` shouldn't have spaces. Though you can access it using `\\` before spaces and special characters:-

```
$('#TICKET\\ NUMBER\\ \\(TK\\)')
```

**DEMO**

```js
$('#TICKET\\ NUMBER\\ \\(TK\\)').css('border', '1px solid red')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="TICKET NUMBER (TK)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note the `id` attribute can't have spaces ([source](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute)).

> The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain any space characters.

Consider using just the CI attribute. If you must identify the element through its ID attribute, consider MD5-ing the ID first.